# How to eliminate code repitition in a ".gitlab-ci.yml"-script that uses stages that are almost identical?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a gitlab-ci/cd.yaml-file that executes 2 test scripts. As you can see there is a lot of repetition going on. As a matter of fact, both stages are identical, except for their "script" value.

For the smoke-suite the value is

- npm run docker_smoke --single-run --progress false

For the regression-suite the value is

- npm run docker_regression --single-run --progress false

```
image: node-karma-protractor

stages:
  - suiteSmoke
  - suiteRegression

before_script:
  - npm install

# Smoke suite =================================
smoke_suite:
  stage: suiteSmoke
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm run docker_smoke --single-run --progress false
  retry: 1
  #saving the HTML-Report
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - reporting/
    expire_in: 1 week
  allow_failure: true

# Regression suite ============================
regression_suite:
  stage: suiteRegression
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm run docker_regression --single-run --progress false
  retry: 1
  #saving the HTML-Report
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - reporting/
    expire_in: 1 week
  allow_failure: true
```

The script needs to adhere to the following rules:

- The tests need to run consecutively (as problems may occur if they're executed in a simultaneous fashion). The order of execution doesn't matter, though.
- If either of the test fails, it gets a second chance and will be executed one more time.
- If one of the tests fails on both attempts and is marked as a 'failed', the other one will still be executed regardless.

Is there a way to eliminate all this repetition via abstraction? How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gitlab provides a couple of [mechanisms](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html) to prevent duplications in your pipelines namely YAML [anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#anchors) and the [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#use-extends-to-reuse-configuration-sections) keyword while the `extends` keyword is recommended for readability.

Applied to your example your pipeline can look like this:

```
image: node-karma-protractor

stages:
  - suiteSmoke
  - suiteRegression

.test:suite:
  stage: suiteSmoke
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  before_script:
    - npm install
  retry: 1
  #saving the HTML-Report
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - reporting/
    expire_in: 1 week
  allow_failure: true

# Smoke suite =================================
smoke_suite:
  extends: .test:suite
  script:
    - npm run docker_smoke --single-run --progress false

# Regression suite ============================
regression_suite:
  extends: .test:suite
  script:
    - npm run docker_regression --single-run --progress false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define templates and then extend your jobs with them.

Documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends

Example:

```
.job-template:
  tags:
    - tag
  allow_failure: true

job1:
  extends:
    - .job-template
  script:
    - do something

job2:
  extends:
    - .job-template
  script:
    - do something
```